# Heroku - Set Procfile to run a Django Command to create DB

Tags: django, heroku

I'm deploying my DjangoApp to Heroku.

I'm following all the documentation but not sure how to set the Procfile to run my command, as I do locally to create my shop_peru DB:

**This is what I do locally to create the Peru DB:**

```
python manage.py ubigeo_peru
```

**This is my Procfile:**

```
release: python manage.py makemigrations
release: python manage.py migrate
release: python manage.py ubigeo_peru
web: gunicorn stickers_gallito.wsgi --log-file -
```

**ubigeo_peru.py:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Peru
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand



tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru-2018-12-25.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        products = [
            Peru(
                departamento=row['departamento'],
                provincia=row['provincia'],
                distrito=row['distrito'],
            )
            for idx, row in tmp_data.iterrows()
        ]

        Peru.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

When deplying to heroku I get this error:

```
    Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 795 bytes | 795.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.8
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 204, in fetch_command
remote:            app_name = commands[subcommand]
remote:        KeyError: 'collectstatic'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 211, in fetch_command
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_1d164976f07d1b5308e0df603fc5a5c0/stickers_gallito/settings.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:            import django_heroku
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to stickers-gallito-app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/stickers-gallito-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/stickers-gallito-app.git'
(stickers_gallito_env) ogonzales@ogonzales:~/Desktop/web_proyects/stickers_gallito$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.07 KiB | 1.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.8
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        167 static files copied to '/tmp/build_48b84f7db1a8a5df5eb464b11621fa61/staticfiles', 67 unmodified, 278 post-processed.
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 115.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
remote:        Released v17
remote:        https://stickers-gallito-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote: 
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "shop_peru" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: INSERT INTO "shop_peru" ("departamento", "provincia", "distr...
remote:                     ^
remote: 
remote: 
remote: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
remote: 
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:     utility.execute()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
remote:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
remote:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:   File "/app/shop/management/commands/ubigeo_peru.py", line 22, in handle
remote:     Peru.objects.bulk_create(products)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
remote:     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 465, in bulk_create
remote:     ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1149, in _batched_insert
remote:     inserted_id = self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db, return_id=True)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1136, in _insert
remote:     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sql
remote:     cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
remote:     return super().execute(sql, params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
remote:     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
remote:     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
remote:     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "shop_peru" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: INSERT INTO "shop_peru" ("departamento", "provincia", "distr...
remote:                     ^
remote: 
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
To https://git.heroku.com/stickers-gallito-app.git
   ab60b75..16f4a2f  master -> master
```

**Structure:**

```
stickers_gallito (project)
   |_shop (app)
     |_management
       |_commands
         |_ubigeo_peru.py
```

**Settings:**

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stickers_gallito.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'ddl7v8vi4kdkip',
        'USER': 'u6sic8t2nrdejq',
        'PASSWORD': 'p72e949360dda1614aabf9a51b531d0c4a5f06ecc7e6528e8454f81687b7a321d',
        'HOST': 'ec2-54-157-94-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

Comment: You *cannot* use sqlite on Heroku. Use one of their hosted db options.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've change my settings to use PostgreSQL but error appears. Could you point me to a proyect on Github to compair my settings? I still think the problem has to do with my `ubigeo_peru` comand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use sqlite database in Heroku. Use on of the databases they provide. 
I generally use postgresql

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

This will create an empty database for you

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}
# add this
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

This is will change the database in your setting.py

Comment: I've updated my question to use PostgreSQL as DB, please se update. I keep seeing the error.

Comment: 1) The error says , it cannot find 'django_heroku' Are you sure you added the pakage to the libraries or installed it successfully?

Comment: 1) The error says , it cannot find 'django_heroku' Are you sure you added the pakage to the libraries or installed it successfully?  2) migrate the database before deploying using 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' 3) Make sure you have all the requirements met for Heroku (dj-database-url, gunicorn, etc)

Comment: I hadn't. PLease update your answer to mark it as the solution.